# Get the selected id index position from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

In my Winforms app, I have a find option. When the user enter an id of my table (note: my `id` is the primary key) I will show the details of particular id that was entered. I store that particular record in datareader and I will display that particular data into textbox fields.

Like this:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
  btnNext.Enabled = true;
  btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
  txtname.Text = reader["name"].ToString();
  .....
}
```

Along with that I have next and previous buttons. So he find data according to that id then he want to see the next record from find id.

I will capture the id of the index position so that I can easily display the next record as well as previous too. How to get id position? Can anyone help?

I displayed next record on my next button like below:

```
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
   if (count < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
   {
   count += 1;
   ShowData();
   }
   else
   {
   MessageBox.Show("Last record of the table.");
   }
   }
```

Comment: Is ID a uuid or just an auto incremental int?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit ID Is uuid. This is unique id. Not autoincrement

Comment: By previous / next, you mean insert order right?

Comment: Actually previous and next or the buttons on my form. i will display the based on index position in my table either next record or previous record.

Comment: I understand that but how do you define the 'next record' is it 'next by insert order', because ordering UUID's makes no sense?

Comment: i said id is unique id only.. This id is entered by the end user.(Just like 100,200,103,so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ROW_NUMBER in Sql Statment to get Current ID position

```
select  ROWNUM from (
          SELECT ID,ROW_NUMBER() over({Your Default Order}) as ROWNUM 
                     FROM {Your Table Name} WHERE {CONDITION} ) x 
                      WHERE x.ID= {Your ID}
```

Eaxmple  `select  ROWNUM from (SELECT ID,ROW_NUMBER() over(ORDER BY ID) as ROWNUM FROM COLORS WHERE NAME like '%%' ) x WHERE x.ID= 5`

Comment: Every time this condition gives ROWNUM as 1 only. If i changed id number also.

Comment: Please type the same code, and note that i remove ')' from end of sataement

Comment: Yes i typed the same code and also removed end brace

Comment: can you try it it in SqlServer Management studio

Comment: Yes this gives the id index number. but how to get this index number from my ui?can i write this in my find stored procedure?

Comment: yes you can write in Stored Procedure select * from (select ID,NAME,ROW_NUMBER() over ......, then in ui you can write  reader["ROWNUM "]

Comment: yes it will be work if we assign reader[""ROWNUM] to count variable.